# Plotly Dash in Kubernetes pod cannot get assets for IFrame

Tags: html, docker, kubernetes, iframe, plotly-dash

The idea is to display .html file in html.iFrame in Plotly Dash hosted in Kubernetes.

The code works as intended in local however it's met with 404 ( in K8s log ) when trying to fetch the file in the pod (/project/assets/). I have went into the pod to check and the files are there. I have checked for file permissions and they are the same as local (-rw-r--r--), parents folders have the same permissions too. I have some other files in /project/cache folders that can be successfully displayed through dcc.Graph indicating that io is fine.

```
100.64.109.71 - - [04/Feb/2022 02:41:58] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 200 -
100.64.109.71 - - [04/Feb/2022 02:41:58] "GET /assets/country/datetime/filename.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Is there something unique about html.iFrame in Kubernetes that I have missed out? My apologies if the question is too terse but I am not even sure where or how to start debugging.

Update 1: Found useful reference ( https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/489 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using srcDoc instead of src.

```
with open(f"assets/{filename}", "r") as f:
    html_content =  f.read()

content = html.Iframe(srcDoc=f"{html_content}", style={"height": "1067px", "width": "98%"})
```